# Should I be able to update a MySQL enum type with a text value?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I'm trying to update the value in a MYSQL enum field from PHP via Doctrine (5.3 and 1.2 respectively).

I get an error when I try and do this:

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->update('StMessages')
            ->set('status','new')
            ->where('message_id = ?',$msg_id);
```

I get a sql state error telling me that the column 'new' does not exist. If I enter 3 instead of new (presumably the internal index of the 'new' value), then the query works. In fact it happens in a SQL client too so perhaps this is a quirk of this version of MySQL? Its 5.1.45.

Anyone know if this is how MySQL is supposed to treat enums or if this is more likely a Doctrine issue? I have 'use_native_enum' set to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this was actually an issue relating to the quoting of strings when updating the field's values. I'm not sure if Doctrine or I was at fault.

Answer (score 0):

Given a table

```
create table test (
     enumfield enum('a','b','c')
);
```

you should be able to do

```
update test set enumfield='a';
```

which is the whole point of the num field - not having to mess with indexes and whatnot.

What's the exact definition of your enum field?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc! "status ENUM('promoted', 'rejected', 'new') DEFAULT 'new'" is the definition of the enum field

Comment: actually its  `status` enum('rejected','promoted','new') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',